# DynamicRoute Plugin for CakePHP giving 404 errors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using this plugin to create slug-based URL's on a CakePHP 2 web application: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-dynamic-route

The documentation suggests that you would call a Cake controller like so:
`posts/view?id=45`

My URL's currently work as Cake's default behaviour. So using the example above `posts/view/45` works but `posts/view?id=45` does not.

When I call URL's as per the example I get a 404 error.

My functions are written like so (e.g. in PostsController.php):

`public function view($id) {
// logic to load post by ID
// ...
}`

There is almost no documentaiton for the above plugin. Has anyone used it or know where I'm going wrong? It seems you cannot pass a GET variable such as 'id' to the 'view' function, without re-factoring the code inside it to accept passed parameters?

Comment: I would say you just didn't understand what that plugin does. From plugin's usage: "*A spec would be the **internal** CakePHP mapping, like `posts/view?id=45`*", but as you wrote, the default is `posts/view/45`. The plugin just allows you to assign a slug to a specific spec.

Comment: Anyway why need to have an URL with parameters, when you're installing a plugin for slugs? That doesn't make a sense. Don't use URLs with parameters (as it doesn't work anyway).

Comment: I understand what the plugin does. I want friendly URL's, like those given in their documentation (e.g. /why-isnt-this-pup-asleep or /manchester/cakephp-developers-dance-to-beyonce). But to set that up you have to route those in the database to an appropriate controller action with an ID. Try using Cake's default as where to route to, and it doesn't work. In other words you can have a "spec" of posts/view?id=45 but not posts/view/45. But your controller won't work passing ?id= to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be that some of the controller functions needed to be re-written to accept GET style parameters.

In the documentation a "spec" field looks like this:
`posts/view?id=45`

In a regular CakePHP application the route for that would be like this: `posts/view/45`

The plugin simply doesn't work if you put the second style of route (posts/view/45) into the "spec" field.

So the answer is the "spec" fields must be like so:
`posts/view?id=45`  and then your controller functions have to be re-written, e.g.

```
public function view($id) {
    if (isset($this->request->params['id'])) {
        $id = $this->request->params['id'];
    }
}
```

Doing this means that it will work with a parameter (view?id=45) or a standard Cake call (view/45).

**Please note this has nothing to do with the "slug" aspect of the plugin** - the "slug" can be anything, as per the documentation examples: `/why-isnt-this-pup-asleep` or `/manchester/cakephp-developers-dance-to-beyonce`. The original question was asking if there was a way to map a "spec" given in the documentation to a Cake controller function *without* having to modify it like I have above. The answer seems to be no, you have to modify them!